# Paypal Checkout with extra info

Tags: php, paypal

First of all, good job on the community for being so helpfull :D

So i have a webshop, with easy paypal checkout:

```
        echo 

        "<form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='business' value='MYMAILYEAH'>

        <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>

        <input type='hidden' name='itemdesc' value='".$row['Description']."' /> 

        <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='".$row['name']."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='".$pricee."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='EUR'>
        <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='".$_POST['iamount']."'>
        <input type='image' name='submit' border='0' src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif' alt='PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online'>

        <input type='hidden' name='address_override' value='1'>

        <input type='hidden' name='first_name' value='".$_SESSION['username']."'>
        </form>";
```

At the moment, when someone buys anything it shows only the price and the name of the object, is it also possible to send any extra notes/item description with it? Because i found out that alot of people didnt have their invoice adres set correctly in paypal...

A huge thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I found a part of the problem and solution:

[image]

I am getting an error at the CITY input;

```
        <input type='hidden' name='first_name' value='".$_SESSION['username']."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='last_name' value='".$_SESSION['username']."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='country' value='NL'>
        <input type='hidden' name='city' value='Arnhem'>
```

What the error says is:

There is a problem with the sendingadres. We marked this RED (the white arrow)
Change the adress and continue paying with paypal.

And under that it says:

This webshop told us to use the sendingadres input from the webshop, and theres a problem with this adres, go back to the webshop to change it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use a post variable directly in your code since the user sets it and can therefore easily manipulate the form.

It doesn't seem to work with the simple form. [Here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) you can find all possible variables.

Comment: Can you tell us your solution as well and move the second question to a separate stackOverflow question?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was;

adding

```
<input type='hidden' name='address_override' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='first_name' value='".$_SESSION['username']."'>
<input type='hidden' name='last_name' value='".$_SESSION['username']."'>
<input type='hidden' name='country' value='NL'>
<input type='hidden' name='city' value='Arnhem'>
```

To override the paypal sendingadres.